# create reusable function for converting data types on multiple pandas columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

i struggle at times with creating reusable functions specifically here for separate subsets of columns ... any advice here?  thanks!

i have some category vars, numeric vars, and a target dep var for classification ... want to create some kind of udf instead of calling the code below ... any ideas?

```
cat_type = lambda x: x.astype("category")
df__[CAT_FEATURES] = df__[CAT_FEATURES].apply(cat_type, axis=0).copy()
num_type = lambda x: x.astype("float")
df__[CON_FEATURES] = df__[CON_FEATURES].apply(num_type, axis=0).copy()
target_type = lambda x: x.astype("category")
df__[TARGET] = df__[TARGET].apply(target_type, axis=0).copy()
```

goal is to create a reusable function to apply to cols to change their data types dynamically

Comment: Your question isn't really clear, what are the inputs to your function? If you're looking for something you can apply dynamically to different columns in different dataframes to convert to different types, then `astype()` _is_ the solution.

Comment: what i have works however wanted to try to make something more automated via a def(..) function

Comment: I understand that piece of what you're trying to do. My clarifying question was about what you want the inputs into your function to be, and what is the scope expected? Named columns in? named columns and types in? `def fix_types(df,cat_cols,num_cols,time_cols):` or `def fix_types(df):#and let the function sort out which is which`

Comment: hmmm ... i actually think def fix_types(df,cat_cols,num_cols,time_cols): makes more sense because then i wouldn't have to hardcode the columns in the scope right?